# What is the correct way to use an intensifier followed by an adjective and then a plural noun? I am specifically interested in the intensifier, "too"

Tags: adjectives

Example: You should not place **too high expectations** on your children.
Using the phrase, "such high expectations"seems to change the meaning slightly.

I´m familiar with the construction too+ adj.+ a+ singular noun (Too pretty a waitress, too dirty a car, too nice a day) and I wonder if there is a similar construction for modifying plural nouns?

Comment: I don't get it. What do you want this expression to mean?

Comment: I want to know if there is a grammatically correct way to say that expectations are too high when you rearrange the sentence so that the noun comes last.

Comment: very high expectations?

Comment: Are you open to other words besides `too`?

Comment: We often have "excessive" expectations

Comment: I´m specifically interested in the intensifier "too", but am open for other options as well.

Comment: @Jennifer: I see. Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: _Too_ is a negative quantifier; _too_ `Adj` _a_ `NP` means _a_ `NP` _that is so_ `Adj` _that not_ `S`, where `S` is unspecified. Too pretty a waitress means a waitress who is so pretty that something unspecified but bad is the case because of her prettiness. This is a special case of the ***so*** `Adj` _a_ `NP` _that_ `S`: _so pretty a waitress_; which means a waitress who is pretty to such a degree that some unspecified proposition is true. That's why _so_ isn't really an intensifier by itself; I always marked off student essays that used _so_ for _very_. It's more complicated than that.

Answer (score 2):

The original construction for singular is "too pretty *of* a day", etc.  I expect that helps make the answer very simple.

> She went to Hollywood with too high of expectations.

Comment: I was under the impression that it was incorrect to use the word "of" in this construction.

Comment: Unfortunately, my digging hasn't turned up a definitive answer for you, so I'm relying a great deal on general knowledge.  However, grammatically there is no reason to believe the construction would have the indefinite article following the adjective.  The greater likelihood is that the preposition (whether "of" or "for") has suffered from elliptical removal in common speech.

Comment: I wonder if a few more examples might help.

Comment: "We were forced to cancel the boat trip because of the too windy conditions."Having too strict rules is not recommended."   I know that I can rearrange the sentences to avoid using this awkward construction, but I want to know the rules that force a rephrasal. My gut instinct says that "too strict of rules" is incorrect, but I have nothing substantial to back it up.

Comment: "Too pretty _of_ a day" is indeed the extended form and you would normally use a matching pattern for plurals: "Too many of the gifts were fake" --> "Too many gifts were fake." The issue with "too high expectations" is that it *doesn't* really work well as "too high of expectations." It's not a very comfortable sentence or statement.

Answer (score 0):

"You should not place too high expectations on your children" seems perfect. "You should not place too high an expectation..." would also mean the same thing.

However, "Too pretty a waitress" isn't the same as "the waitress is so very pretty". It has a subtle connotation that a waitress this pretty, could be in a better career, say modelling or something else.

A few more examples:

1. "This is too simple a question to ask an expert" means "This is such a simple question that (anyone will be able to answer and) you don't need an expert".
2. "You are too tall a girl for me" means I don't need a girl as tall as you are.

Answer (score 0):

Jennifer: "too high expectations" does not work for me, for reasons which have more to do with my ear than with adjectives modified by adverbs. Given that 'overly high expectations' and 'unrealistically high expectations' work fine, it may be because the 'too high' construction is a tautology: obvioulsy we should not have expectations that are too high because of the fact that they are too high. 'Too high + noun' seems to me to be an absolute, and what you are looking for is a comparative construction, i.e expectations that are too high for them, but not too high in an absolute sense.

Answer (score -1):

I would have thought...

"You should not place too high an expectations on your children."

"We were forced to cancel the boat trip due to too windy conditions."

"Having too strict a set of rules is not recommended."

...but then I am no expert ;)